# Como mostrar um vetor sem ir para outra pagina

Tags: javascript, html5

Bom estou fazendo um pagina que faz sorteios, eu já consegui fazer já metade do trabalho, porém quando eu vou mostrar o resultado do vetor ele vai para outra pagina, queria saber como poder mostrar o que tem no vetor na mesma pagina.

Meu html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Gerador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    <script src="interacao.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
<body>
   <h1 id="principal">Gerador de apostas</h1>
 <hgroup id="menu">
    <a href="file:///D:/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/Gerador%20de%20apostas/index.html"><p>Inicio</p></a>
    <a href="file:///D:/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/Gerador%20de%20apostas/gerador.html"><p>Gerador</p></a>
    <a href="file:///D:/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/Gerador%20de%20apostas/sobre.html"><p>Sobre</p></a>
</hgroup>
<hgroup id="apostas">
    <button onclick="mega()">Mega-Sena</button>
    <button onclick="lotofacil()">Quina</button>
    <button onclick="quina()">Lotomania</button>
    <button onclick="lotomania()">LotoFácil</button>
</hgroup>
```

Meu javascript

```
function mega(void) {

   var numeros = [];
   var numero,verifica;
   for(var i=0;i<6;i++)
   {
      do
      {
           numero = Math.floor(Math.random()*61);
           verifica = false;
           for(var j=0; j < i;j++)
           {
              if (numeros[j]==numero) {
                verifica=true;
              }
            }

       }while(verifica);
       numeros.push(numero);
    }
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
       document.write(numeros[i]);
    }
```

}

Comment: A minha resposta não resolve o problema?

Comment: Obrigado, eu tinha me esquecido de marcar como resolvido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem muitas formas de fazer isso, é possível criar elementos na mesma página e também é possível atualizar informações de elementos na página, que é o mais comum de se fazer. Eu achei que fica mais legal preenchendo os input's com os valores gerados:

```js
function mega() {
  var mega = document.getElementsByClassName('mega'); 
  var numeros = [];
  var numero,verifica;
  for(var i=0;i<6;i++)
  {
    do
    {
      numero = Math.floor(Math.random()*61);
      verifica = false;
      for(var j=0; j < i;j++)
      {
        if (numeros[j]==numero) {
          verifica=true;
        }
      }
    }while(verifica);
    numeros.push(numero);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<6;i++)
  {
    mega[i].value=numeros[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mega()">Mega-Sena</button>
<div>
  <input class="mega" type="text" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" readonly>
  <input class="mega" type="text" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" readonly>
  <input class="mega" type="text" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" readonly>
  <input class="mega" type="text" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" readonly>
  <input class="mega" type="text" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" readonly>
  <input class="mega" type="text" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;" readonly>
</div>
```

> O números da MEGA-SENA vai do 1 ao 60, a sua função pode atribuir zero na combinação, por isso a linha que gera os números deve ser: `numero = Math.floor((Math.random() * 60) + 1);`
>   Veja: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp